# variable ambit and sending parameters in php OO

Tags: php, oop, parameters, scope

I'm very confused about using the parameters through pages with PHP OO.
I'm following a tutorial about creating a framework (it's just like the Zend Framework); but, what I don't understand is when this happens:

Example, the index:

```
// File: sourcefiles/index.php

define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).DS );
define ('APP_PATH',(ROOT.'aplicacion'));

require_once APP_PATH. DS.'Config.php';
require_once APP_PATH. DS.'Request.php';
require_once APP_PATH. DS.'BootStrap.php';
require_once APP_PATH. DS.'Controller.php';
require_once APP_PATH. DS.'View.php';

try
{
    BootStrap::run(new Request());
```

I have:

```
 // File: sourcefiles/controladores/IndexController.php
 <?php
        class IndexController extends Controller
        {
            public function __construct() {
                parent::__construct();
            }

            public function indexAction() 
            {
                 $this->view->titulo='Homepage';
                 $this->view->contenido='Whatever';
                 $this->view->renderizar('index');   
            }
        }
   ?>
```

And this:

```
// file : sourcefiles/aplicacion/View.php
<?php

class View
{
    private $controlador;
    private $layoutparams;

    public function __construct(Request $peticion)
    {
        $this->controlador = $peticion->getControlador();
    }

    public function renderizar($vista,$item=false)
    {
        $rutaview = ROOT.'vistas'.DS.$this->controlador.DS.$vista.'.phtml';

        if (is_readable($rutaview))
        {
            include_once $rutaview;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception('Error de vista');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And here is the View:

```
// file : sourcefiles/vistas/index/index.phtml

<h1>
    Vista index..
    <?php
    echo $this->titulo;
    echo $this->contenido;
    ?>
</h1>
```

Now my questions are:

How the IndexController can use the line? `$this->view->titulo = blabla;` 
The view class doesn't have a "titulo" attribute; however, I can do that. But here is a curious thing, if I do that after calling the `$this->view->renderizar('index')`, I get the error.

How does the index.phtml file knows this? `echo $this->titulo;` because, there isn't a include or require called, it's confusing to me.

When I do a require or include call in a file, the required or included file knows the caller's variables?

If somebody can explain these to me, I would really appreciate it :D
or link me to a discussion on official information about this, or how is this called?

Answer (score 1):

Think of an `include` or `require` line as "copy-and-pasting" the code from one file into another. This isn't quite accurate, but it explains part of the behaviour here:

In `sourcefiles/aplicacion/View.php` you include `sourcefiles/vistas/index/index.phtml` while **inside** the function `View->renderizar`. So all the code in `index.phtml` gets loaded as though it was happening inside that function too. This is why you can access `$this`, for instance.

As for referencing `$this->view->titulo` when you haven't defined it, this is PHP letting you be lazy. Just like any variable, a member on an object will spring into life as soon as you mention it, with only a notice warning that maybe you made a mistake.

Comment: Thank you, now i do understand what is this all about. You deserve the heaven!! :D